# EM wave: Why do you take the imaginary part of complex $H(z,t)$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, conventions, complex-numbers

The following is an electromagnetic wave traveling in +z direction:

$$\vec{E}(z,t) = 1.0~e^{-\alpha z} e^{j(2\pi f t - \beta z)}~\hat{y}$$

$$\vec{H}(z,t) = - (2.28\times 10^3)~ e^{-\alpha z}~e^{j(2\pi f t - \beta z - \frac{\pi}{4})}~\hat{x}$$

The part I don't understand is this: Why does the textbook say to take the imaginary part of $\vec{H}(x,t)$ to convert it to this form:

$$\vec{H}(z,t) = - (2.28\times 10^3)~ e^{-\alpha z}~\sin\big(2\pi f t - \beta z - \frac{\pi}{4}\big)~\hat{x}$$

I understand what they are doing:

$$\text{Im}\{~e^{j\theta}~\} = \text{Im}\{\cos(\theta) + j~\sin(\theta)~ \}= \sin(\theta) $$

I just don't understand why they want the imaginary part instead of the real part...   and how is that equivalent to the complex form?

Would you for instance take the imaginary part of $\vec{E}(z,t)$ a well to get the sin form?  or does that one need to be the real part...  really, there's no explanation in this book.

Maybe its just a trick to place the wave equations in complex form because there's always an implied hidden operator around the complex exponential to  pluck out the imaginary part in the end?

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: This question is really missing some context. Just taking the imaginary without explaining what you're trying to get isn't helpful

Comment: You can choose either, because the only difference is a phase difference of $\pi/2$, but you need to be consistent.

Comment: seems like writing EM wave as a complex exponential is a mathematical convenience, and there's implicitly either an Re{} or Im{} around the whole thing that people get tired of writing...

Comment: @pico That is exactly correct, except that it is essentially always the real part that is what you are actually interested in.  For some reason, your book is using the imaginary part instead, and without more context, it is not possible to know whether this is just an idiosyncrasy of the author, or if the imaginary part was chosen for a logical reasons.

Comment: Possibly the choice depends on if you want your field to have max amplitude or zero amplitude at time zero...